# TensorFlow's placeholder size

Tags: tensorflow, input, batchsize

I am getting confused in how to use placeholder for batch training. In my code, input image is of size 3 x 3. In order to do batch training, I am setting `tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,3,3])`.

When I try to give batches of 3x3 as an input, TensorFlow gives an error that

```
Cannot feed value of shape (3, 3) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 3, 3).
```

Below is the code

```py
input = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,3,3])
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(placeholder, feed_dict{placeholder:input})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your placeholder is of shape `None x 3 x 3` so you need to feed in data that has **3** dimensions, even if the first dimension just has size 1 (i.e. a `1 x 3 x 3` in your case instead of a `3 x 3`). One easy way to add an extra dimension (of size 1) to to an array is to do `array[None]`. If `array` has shape `3 x 3` then `array[None]` has shape `1 x 3 x 3`. So you can update your code to

```py
inputs = np.array([[1, 1 ,1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None, 3, 3])
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(placeholder, feed_dict{placeholder: inputs[None]})
```

(I changed `input` to `inputs` because `input` is a keyword in Python and shouldn't be used as a variable name)

Note that you won't want to do `inputs[None]` if `inputs` is already 3D. If it might be 2D or 3D, you'll need a condition like `inputs[None] if inputs.ndim == 2 else inputs`.

Comment: shouldn't the placeholder be tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[3,3,None]) as the batch training will increase the input size in 3rd dimension like first input will be 3 x 3 x 1, second batch input will make the input as 3 x 3 x 2.Why at first place it is tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None, 3, 3]). This shows that 3rd dimenion is fixed at 3. Any explanation for that?

Comment: The usual convention is to put the batch dimension first